# async to delay e.handled in a KeyDown event

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Let's assume we have this:

```
private void Input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

And then i add `async-await` like this:

```
private async void Input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Shouldn't that do the same, but only delay it for a second? So why doesn't it?

**NOTE:**

I'm not seeking for debugging help, i'm just wondering why can't i use `async-await` to delay handling the `KeyDown`

Comment: what does it do instead?

Comment: nothing, like it's never there~

Comment: @MilenPavlov event handlers should be `async void`

Comment: @MilenPavlov that's right, you can't `task` it.

Comment: `e.Handled` marks the event as handled. What do you mean by "does nothing"? it shouldn't be doing much.

Comment: That's right, so when i use async as i did there it should delete whatever i type after a second from the `KeyDown` right? but it does not! that's what i meant.

Comment: You are confusing KeyEventArgs.Handled with KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress.  Only the latter can prevent typing keys from being processed.  Which will *not* work when you await a delay, the KeyPress event was already fired by the time the delay expires and the keystroke was already added to the control.  Setting SuppressKeyPress to true is now too late.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i'm just wondering why can't i use async-await to delay handling the KeyDown

Event handlers are synchronous by definition. So, unless your code has a way to inform the event handler that it is acting asynchronously (e.g., a WinStore-style Deferral), then it must do all "communication" (e.g., `KeyEventArgs.Handled`) before its first `await`.

If you need to delay input in general, I recommend converting the code to use [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to use await in an event handler. The "synchronous part" of event handler does nothing.

```
void OnKeyDown()
{
    Keys keyData = ...;
    KeyEventArgs args = new KeyEventArgs(keyData);
    // Thread-safe event raiser, 
    // equalient to KeyDown(this, args);
    RaiseKeyDownEvent(args);
    // Returns immediatelly when you reach
    // the first await method call
    bool isHandled = args.Handled;
    // In the meantime event handler
    // is awaiting for Task.Delay(),
    // but we have already saved Handled value
}

// This code does nothing useful
private async void Input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Will return there
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    // The execution will be continued from there
    e.Handled = true;
}

// But this code will handle input, but without any delay
private async void Input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Yes i know it does nothing but why not? shouldn't it input e.g. `G`  when i press the `G` button until the `e.handled` executes then the `G` gets deleted?

Comment: Because the event handler executes sychronously. Windows Forms event handlers are synchronous, so "async void" actually starts executing your code on a different thread. See my comments on OnKeyDown() method, and you can read further in Richter's CLR via C#.

Comment: *"async void" actually starts executing your code on a different thread*. That is not true. there is nothing about `async void` which makes it invoke on a different thread. On the contrary, event handlers whill be executes on the UI thread.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov that was a simplification in order to explain why this code doesn't work. Otherwise, it would take a lot of time to copypaste the whole chapter from the Richter's book :)